# Estimate involving Besov norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, interpolation-spaces, variational-inequalities

When reading some old notes of my advisor on interpolation spaces, I bumped into a problem I can't quite wrap my head around. Here are the details.

For $p\in(0,\infty)$  a $p$-variation semi-norm of a function $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{V_p(\mathbb{R})}=\sup_{J\in\mathbb{N}} \sup_{t_{0}<\ldots<t_{J}}\Big(\sum_{j=0}^{J-1}  | f(t_{j+1})-f(t_{j}) |^{p} \Big)^{1/p}
\end{align*}
and the $L^p$ norm of $f$ is
$$
\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|^p\, dx\right)^{1/p}.
$$

Let $\phi$ be a Schwartz function on $\mathbb{R}$ with $supp(\widehat{\phi})\subset\{1/2\le |\xi|\le 2\}$ and for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ define
$\phi_k(x)=2^k\phi(2^k x)$.

The claim I'd like to prove is that if $p>1$, then the following estimate holds
\begin{align*}
\|f\ast \phi_k\|_{V_p(\mathbb{R})}\le C 2^{k/p}\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})},
\end{align*}
with some $C>0$. $\textbf{The hint}$ given in the notes is to use Plancherel-Polya inequality.

I can't see how to use the hint. I found some papers on sampling theory mentioning Plancherel-Polya inequality, but the inequality wasn't stated explicitly; at least not in the form I could apply to this problem.  Instead, I tried proving it more directly by applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to expressions $f\ast\phi_k(t_{j+1})-f\ast\phi_k(t_{j})$ and using smoothness of $\phi$, but I couldn't get the right power of $2^k$.

Any help will be appreciated!

I editted the question after Fedja's comment.

Comment: To start with, are you sure that the RHS of your inequality should not have the $L^p$-norm $\|f\|_{L^p}$ of the original function rather than that of the (multiplicative?) convolution?

Comment: Yes, I believe I wrote the inequality correctly. The idea is that if we choose $\phi$ such that $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \widehat{\phi}(2^{-k}\xi)=1$, for $\xi\neq 0$, then summing up the postulated inequality over $k$ implies the estimate $\|f\|_{V_p}\lesssim \|f\|_{B_{p,1}^{1/p}}$, where $B_{p,1}^{1/p}$ is a Besov space. The convolution is additive (I could've written $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}_+$).

Comment: @fedja Now when I thought about it, proving the inequality with $\|f\|_{L^p}$ on the RHS would be sufficient for the appplication to Besov norm estimate that I mentioned in the previous comment. So, if you have any idea how to prove, I'd love to see it!

Comment: Do you need $2^{k/p}$? What do you obtain, instead? I do not see how to use Plancherel-Polya, since the points $(t_j)$ can be arbitrarily close each other. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Yes, I need $2^{k/p}$. Meanwhile, I got only $2^{(2-1/p)k}$.  And I also can't see how to use Plancherel-Polya.

Comment: For $p=1$ the variation seminorm og $g$ can be estimated by $\|g'\|_1$ and for $p=\infty$ by $2\|g\|_\infty$. Now apply this to $g=f*\phi_k$ with a fixed $k$ and you get $2^k \|f\|_1$ and $2\|f\|_\infty$. Now apply Riesz-Thorin to the linear operator $f \mapsto \left (f*\phi (t_{j+1})-f*\phi (t_j)\right )$ from $L^p$ to $\ell^p$ and you get $2^{k/p}$.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot!